# Browsing/download/streaming through browser limited. Why?

Tags: networking, router, internet, optical-cable

I have a weird problem.

My plans allows 100 Mbps.

Almost all Internet speed testing sites show my download at around 17-18 Mbps. But upload is steady at around 90 Mbps.

This affects browsing, streaming via browsers and downloading via browsers.

When downloading through torrents, however, the download sometimes works at rated speeds and sometimes at limited speeds mentioned above.

Uploading is not a problem anywhere.

I tried resetting my router. I checked the signal strength of the optical fiber. By checking i mean i showed it to a technician, or what passes for a technician in a corporate.

What else can i do?

Comment: What speed are you paying for? Lots of ISPs throttle torrents. Torrents are also very dependent on their host and seeders available. You haven't actually said anything that indicates or details any problem.

Comment: *"Almost all Internet speed testing sites show my download at around 17-18 Mbps"* - With the information given, it might be difficult to diagnose "why" your speeds are different. But upload and download speeds can certainly be asymmetrical (though usually in reverse i.e. low-speed uploads and high-speed downloads).